# Merge two string into a float on an stm32?

Tags: c, string, floating-point

I receive two string values over the UART to an stm32f3 and would like to concatenate them to a float, but I actually don't see how to do this. Let's
do this in the example below.

```
char *s1="100";
char *s2="09"; //should result in 100.09

float x=???(s1,s2);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the _strings_ negative like `char *s1="100";
char *s2="-09";` or `"-100"; "-09";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to print both strings into a buffer, and then use `strtod` to read a `float` back:

```
char buf[10];
sprintf(buf, "%.4s.%.4s", s1, s2);
float f = strtod(buf, NULL);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

Note that since `100.09` has no precise representation as a `float`, the result would be something close to `100.089996`.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/b7WkZ3)

Comment: strtod does not exist on the stm32 and sscanf seems not to work. my buf looks like the following: buf={'1','0','0','.','0','9','\n','\0','\0'....} and val is a float. Then I call it like this: sscanf(buf,"%f",&val); but val becomes some random very small value.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft It's odd that `strtod` is not available. I assume you included `stdlib.h`, right? Given the content of the `buf`, `sscanf` should work, assuming that `val` is a `float`, not a `double`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd convert each string to an integer, then use arithmetic:

```
int whole = atoi(s1);
int frac = atoi(s2);

float x = whole + frac / powf(10, strlen(s2));
```

The last part computes 10^strlen(s2) because "09" means 09/100, "5" means 5/10, etc.

If `powf()` doesn't work on your system (as you said in a comment), you can use this (only good for small non-negative inputs but that's what you have):

```
float myexp10(unsigned x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1.0;

    float res = 10;
    while (--x)
        res *= 10;

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Or `float x = whole + frac * powf(10, - (int)strlen(s2));`

Comment: @HansPeterLoft: How about `pow()`?  It's equally fine here, and I'm pretty sure it works on STM32.  You may need to link with `libm` by adding the compiler/linker option `-lm`, or explain what you mean by "not working."

Comment: @HansPeterLoft, if powf is not working, then implement it.

Comment: @HansPeterLoft: I wrote you a replacement function in case your system really doesn't have `pow()`.

Comment: Well, if you end up writing a custom `myexp10`, you could also just write a custom `float my_decimal_part(const char *)`...

Answer (score 1):

I would concatenate the two strings, with a dot in between, and then use [strtof()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) to extract the float number, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char *s1 = "100";
    char *s2 = "09";
    char s[strlen(s1) + 1 + strlen(s2) + 1];
    strcpy(s, s1);
    strcat(s, ".");
    strcat(s, s2);
    float result = strtof (s, NULL);
    printf("%f\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 100.089996

If that precision is not enough for you, then use [`strtod()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/), like this:

```
double result = strtod (s, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple but tedious approach is to store them in char array and use `atof()` for conversion as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <stdlib.h> /* atof */


float str2float(const char* s1, const char* s2)
{
    int size = strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 2;
    char a[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); ++i)
        a[i] = s1[i];
    a[strlen(s1)] = '.';

    for(int i = strlen(s1)+1, j = 0; i < size && j < strlen(s2); ++i, ++j)
        a[i] = s2[j];

    a[size] = '\0';

    return (float)atof(a);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s1="100";
    char *s2="09"; 

    printf("%.2f\n", str2float(s1,s2));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider scaling the fractional part and adding as suggest by others.

```
  char *s1="100";
  char *s2="09";
  float f1 = strtof(s1, (void*) NULL); 
  unsigned n = strlen(s2);
  float f2 = strtof(s2, (void*) NULL)/powf(10, n);
  return f1 + f2;
```

This is usually sufficient, yet to dig a bit deeper.

`strtof(s2, (void*) NULL)/powf(10, n);` incurs a rounding with the division as the quotient, a fraction, is rarely exactly representable as a [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  Then the addition `f1 + f2` may incur another rounding.  The sum is sometimes then not the best `float` answer due to [double rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Double_rounding).

To greatly reduce the chance of *double rounding*, code can easily use higher precision like `double`.

```
  float f1 = strtof(s1, (void*) NULL); 
  unsigned n = strlen(s2);
  double f2 = strtod(s2, (void*) NULL)/pow(10, n); // use higher precision
  return f1 + f2;
```

Alternatively code may avoid wider FP math and use exact integer math first to combine the values and then divide, incurring only 1 rounding.  This will make for a more accurate answer once in a while.

```
  long l1 = strtol(s1, (void*) NULL, 10); 
  long l2 = strtol(s2, (void*) NULL, 10); 
  unsigned n = strlen(s2);
  long p10 = pow10(n);  // Trivial user TBD code

  long sum = l1*p10 + l2;  // Exact unless `long` overflow
  return 1.0f*sum/p10;     // `float` conversion exact for value up to about 1/FLT_EPSILON
```

---

The above works well if `s1` is *negative*.  Also OK with `s2` as a *negative* aside from more code needed to extract the digit width than `strlen(s2)`.

Else it is hard to beat a string concatenation and convert.  I recommend `float strof()` over `double atof()` as 1) `atof()` lacks defined behavior on overflow, 2) `atof()` uses `double` math, which may be slower.

```
size_t l1 = strlen(s1);
size_t l2 = strlen(s1);
char buffer[l1 + 1 + l2 + 1];  // Or use a fixed wide buffer with test to insure fit
strcpy(buffer, s1);
buffer[l1] = '.';
strcpy(buffer + l1 + 1, s1);
return strtof(buffer, (void *) NULL);
```